# Formatting Cell in WPF DataGrid

Tags: wpf, datagrid, cell-formatting

Say I have a DataGrid with its ItemsSource binding to a data table(whose columns are various). One column of the table is double type with several NaN values. While on the display part, I want to format all the NaN value to blank.

What I did is to set a style to the DataGridCell like this:

```
<Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
    <Setter Property="Content" Value="{Binding Converter={StaticResource NumberConverter}}" />
</Style>
```

But it doesn't work because the DataContext of the cell is DataRowView which means I cannot get which column I was at in the converter.

Any one has a good idea? 
Thanks a lot.

Comment: You case use `ResourceDictionary` in XAML to define the `NumberConverter`, not needing each instance per the `DataGridCell`.

Comment: You are right, I just want to show more detail of how I'm doing; but actually, this is not solution to solve my issue. I tried to create a DoubleWrpper class which has explicit operator double; then I create the column to my new class as one of the column in the datatable. I cannot go further too in this way because the column will be sorted by string not by double. Then I try to implement ICompare interface and it still has no effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, what I want to do is to convert the NaN cells to blank. So I created the DataTable and generate the DataColumn which allows DBNull. When the value is NaN in the datasource, I can set the value to DBNull.Value so that the NaN shows nothing in my DataGrid. Hope it helps if you have the same issue.